# Parsing JSON and forming a customized array

Tags: javascript, html, json

**What I have,**

```
{
    "rowId": "1",
    "product_name": [
        "Product 1",
        "Product 2",
        "Product 3",
        "Product 4",
        "Product 5"
    ],
    "product_tag": [
        "1112231",
        "1112232",
        "1112233",
        "1112234",
        "1112235"
    ],
    "version_id": [
        "1.0",
        "2.0",
        "1.5",
        "3.0",
        "2.5"
    ]
}
```

**How I would like it to get transformed.** (i.e, taking every element from each array in the JSON given above and forming a new array like below).

```
{
    [
        "Product 1", 
        "1112231",
        "1.0"
    ],
    [
        "Product 2", 
        "1112232",
        "2.0"
    ],
    [
        "Product 3", 
        "1112233",
        "1.5"
    ],
    [
        "Product 4", 
        "1112234",
        "3.0"
    ],
    [
        "Product 5", 
        "1112235",
        "2.5"
    ]
}
```

**What I've tried**,

I've tried using the `flatMap` function of javascript (given below) but with no luck. (Note: Here **testData** refers to the JSON data pasted above)

```
[testData.product_name, testData.product_tag, testData.version_id].flatMap((i, index) => i[index]);
```

which returns only one record like this (where I need to get 5 in my case),

```
["Product 1","1112232","1.5"]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: please add a valid result. you can not have arrays in an object without a property name.

Comment: @NinaScholz I agree, but this is how I'm getting the data from the backend unfortuatenly, There is no way to change it.

Comment: @Rajesh I do agree Rajesh, Please refer to the earlier response.

Comment: Nina's asking about the output, not the input. The input is fine

Comment: what if all the arrays dont have equal length ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I hope, I will have the arrays served in the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```js
const input={"rowId":"1","product_name":["Product 1","Product 2","Product 3","Product 4","Product 5"],"product_tag":["1112231","1112232","1112233","1112234","1112235"],"version_id":["1.0","2.0","1.5","3.0","2.5"]}

const { product_name, product_tag, version_id } = input;

const output = 
  Array.from(input.product_name, (name, i) => ([ name, product_tag[i], version_id[i] ]))

console.log(output)
```

If you have unequal number of items in each array, you could get the biggest array's length to create the output

```
// or Math.min if you don't want undefined items
const length = Math.max(product_name.length, product_tag.length, version_id.length)

const output = 
  Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => ([ product_name[i] , product_tag[i], version_id[i] ]))
```

Comment: This will only copy upto `input.product_name.length` items, what if its unequal

Comment: @KunalMukherjee that is for OP to decide. OP's question doesn't seem to indicate this. And, we answer to the [mcve] provided in the question

Comment: @Adiga Awesome!. I was repeatedly trying to use the `flatMap`, this one looks more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the value/arrays and assign the items to the array with the same index.

```js
var object = { rowId: "1", product_name: ["Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4", "Product 5"], product_tag: ["1112231", "1112232", "1112233", "1112234", "1112235"], version_id: ["1.0", "2.0", "1.5", "3.0", "2.5"] },
    result = Object.values(object).reduce((r, a) => {
        Array.isArray(a) && a.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use construct an array including the `product_name`, `product_tag` and `version_id` in the order you prefer. This is to make sure that the order is right. Use `reduce` to loop thru the array. Use `forEach` to loop in the inner array.

```js
let data = {"rowId":"1","product_name":["Product 1","Product 2","Product 3","Product 4","Product 5"],"product_tag":["1112231","1112232","1112233","1112234","1112235"],"version_id":["1.0","2.0","1.5","3.0","2.5"]}

let result = [data.product_name, data.product_tag, data.version_id].reduce((c, v) => {
  v.forEach((e, i) => {
    c[i] = c[i] || [];
    c[i].push(e);
  });
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = obj.product_name.map((it,index)=>[it,obj.product_tag[index],obj.version_id[index]])
```

Comment: add some explanation to your solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use do it like this if you want

```
 const ar= {
    "rowId": "1",
    "product_name": [
        "Product 1",
        "Product 2",
        "Product 3",
        "Product 4",
        "Product 5"
    ],
    "product_tag": [
        "1112231",
        "1112232",
        "1112233",
        "1112234",
        "1112235"
    ],
    "version_id": [
        "1.0",
        "2.0",
        "1.5",
        "3.0",
        "2.5"
    ]
};
let newAr = {};

for(var i = 0;i < ar.product_name.length;i++){
    newAr[i]= [ar.product_name[i],ar.product_tag[i],ar.version_id[i]];

}
```